# Can't add checked property for checkbox

Tags: javascript

```
<input type=checkbox id="chk1" name="chk" onclick="getchecked('chk1')"/>
<input type=checkbox id="chk2" name="chk" onclick="getchecked('chk2')"/>

getchecked(pId)
{
  if(pId.checked==true)
    alert('ok');
  else
    alert('not ok');
}
```

In my runtime if i checked any checkbox it does not add the checked property for that checkbox, I verified that in Developer tool bar.

So it always entering into else block Why?

Comment: Maybe because you want the DOM object "chk1", but you're passing a Javascript string literal 'chk1' instead?

Comment: You question is quite incomplete, where are you trying to call that function, in any other function or on the checkbox click or change event itself??

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
<input type=checkbox id="chk1" name="chk" onclick="getchecked(this)"/>
<input type=checkbox id="chk2" name="chk" onclick="getchecked(this)"/>

function getchecked(checkbox)
{
  if(checkbox.checked)
    alert('ok');
  else
    alert('not ok');
}
```

I.e. pass the checkbox-object to the function instead of it's ID. Otherwise you would have to use `var checkbox = getElementById(pId)` inside the function, before you can call `checkbox.checked`.

Also the `function` keyword is missing in your question (I guess that's a copy/paste error).